# transfer of ERC721 between EOA to contract

Tags: mining, contract-debugging, erc-721, eoa

If I have contract A and contract B (which follows erc721 standards), both have implemented the `OnERC721Received` function, how does the transfer of any tokenId take place atomically?

If I have a token with `tokenId` X (uint256) in contract A and owned by Y( address) and the contract B also has a minted token with the same `tokenId` X, will transferring that token from A to B takes place, if yes doesn't the tokenId collide? how does it work under the hood, does it change the owner to contract B or mint a new token in contract B and burn from A?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer won't collide even the tokenID is the same between two different contracts.

In fact, whenever we talk about "*transferring*" tokens, this means updating the balance within the token contract and assigning a new ownership (after the approval). This is an example from an ERC721 implementation of the mapping where the ownership is updated after a transfer:

```
// Mapping from token ID to owner address
mapping (uint256 => address) private _owners;
```

Therefore, in your example, a transfer of `tokenId` **X** from contract **A** to contract **B** will just update the ownership in contract **A** for `tokenId` X with the contract **B** address.

Comment: thanks! can you add a link to that mapping example, please? if I am using openzeppelin's erc721, is this pre-implemented?

Comment: Yep, here it is:  https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol